# Keycloak not enforcing group authorization policies

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have set up two web applications (`app1` and `app2`) and I am using Keycloak to handle authentication. To do this I set up 2 clients (`client1` for `app1`, `client2` for `app2`). So far this works fine and I am able to login to my apps.

But now I want to add some restrictions:

- I have created 2 users (`user1` and `user2`).
- I want `user1` to only have access to `app1`
- I want `user2` to only have access to `app2`
- I will also have other users that will need access to both `app1` and `app2`, sometimes at different levels. (e.g. `user3` could be an admin user for `app1` but a regular user for `app2`

To try and get this to work, I haver done the following

- I have created 2 groups, `user1` belongs to `group1` and `user2` belongs to `group2`.
- Clients > client1/client2 > authorization > policies

  - Deleted existing policy
  - Create policy > group > configured the policies accordingly
- Clients > client1/client2 > authorization > permissions > created a new permission
- Authorization is enabled, standard authentication flow is enabled, implicit flow is disabled

Despite configuring all these settings, `user1` and `user2` can still login to both applications, its as if authorization is being ignored.

How do I get this to work??

Regarding the apps:

- `app1` is a web application running on Spring Boot 1.5
- `app2` is a web application running on Spring Boot 2.7
- For both applications, I have configured properties like `authorization-uri`, `token-uri`, `user-info-uri` etc.

I am using keycloak 21.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found what I was looking for...

While KeyCloak lets you define roles for your application, it does not actually enforce these roles! Instead, these roles are passed to the application as part of the JWT Token. It is the applications responsibility to enforce these roles.

In Spring Boot, an extra step is required. You need to create a class that implements `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` in order to map the JWT roles to authorities in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions.
First (roughly) : Assuming your applications have API + Frontend, you have to put Frontend Access Type to public &  API Access Type to bearer-only. Then you have to configure both sides with infos from Keycloak :

- realm
- auth-server-url
- client
  and with your API configure Routes will need Authorization.
  Your frontend will connect to KC, get a JWT token, send this token to your API, which will send to KC to verify, and in return if that's ok you will authorize access to your Route.

Second: Create two different Realms to put your clients on, and they're will not able to communicate

Comment: Hi, Regarding option 1: ```app1``` and ```app2``` are spring boot applications that have already been configured with ```accessTokenUri```, ```userAuthorizationUri``` etc. Regarding option 2: This would not work for me since I also have users that require access to both applications. I will update my questions to clarify.